# Regenerate all integers in a pk column from zero and keep previous value in another column

Tags: mysql, row-number

I need to regenerate all primary key numbers from zero and keep previous amount in ex column but the query doesnt work :

```
update mh_product AS p,(select p.id AS oldid,row_number() OVER (order by p.id asc)-1 AS newid from p) AS bp set p.id=bp.newid,p.ex=bp.oldid
```

I have this table

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | ex       |
+-----------+----------+
| 24        | 0        |
| 25        | 0        |
| 27        | 0        |
| 29        | 0        |
| 30        | 0        |
+-----------+----------+
```

and need to convert to this :

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | ex       |
+-----------+----------+
| 0         | 24       |
| 1         | 25       |
| 2         | 27       |
| 3         | 29       |
| 4         | 30       |
+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually suggest considering *not* doing this update, the reason being that if your data changes again in the future, you might be forced to run the update multiple times.

Instead, consider just querying with a select to view the data you want:

```sql
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - 1 AS id,
    id AS ex
FROM mh_product
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided is almost correct, but there is a small syntax error that needs to be corrected. The table alias p is being used inside the subquery select p.id..., but p has not been defined yet. Instead, you should use the subquery's table alias bp to reference the id column:
Please use this as the solution.

```
UPDATE mh_product AS p, (
        SELECT p.id AS oldid, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.id ASC)-1 AS newid
          FROM mh_product AS p) AS bp
   SET p.id = bp.newid, 
       p.ex = bp.oldid;
```